# Protocol Buffers .NET inheritance

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have data in a Protocol Buffers format which can be described as follows

```proto
message Sections {
    repeated Section sections = 1;
}

message Section {
    required uint32 type = 1;
    required bytes payload = 2;
}

message SectionType1 {
    required int32 fieldType1 = 1;
    // ...
}

message SectionType2 {
    required int32 fieldType2 = 1;
    // ...
}

message SectionType3 {
    required int32 fieldType3 = 1;
    // ...
}
```

I’m using the protobuf-net library (+ protogen + precompile).
How do I deserialize such data into DTOs similar to

```cs
public class Sections
{
    public List<Section> Sections { get; }
}

public abstract class Section
{
}

public class SectionType1 : Section
{
    public int FieldType1 { get; }
}

public class SectionType2 : Section
{
    public int FieldType2 { get; }
}

public class SectionType3 : Section
{
    public int FieldType3 { get; }
}
```

Is it possible to work with such data from .NET (using precompilation since I’m on a light framework)?

Comment: Protocol buffers are for serializing information--in a flat and sequential way.  You should consider any types you use in things like this as "shapes", that just contain data, no inheritance or behaviour.  See Data Transfer Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you would have to do it manually - i.e. have

```
[ProtoContract]
public abstract class Section
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] public int Type {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)] public byte[] Payload {get;set;}
}
```

and handle the rest manually. protobuf-net inheritance maps top the *following* .proto schema:

```
message Section {
    optional SectionType1 Type1 = 1;
    optional SectionType2 Type2 = 2;
    optional SectionType3 Type3 = 3;
}
```

where we have, say:

```
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(SectionType1)]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(SectionType2)]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(SectionType3)]
public abstract class Section
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add my findings, I created .proto file which has one base class and 20 derived classes.
I generated the code via protobuf-net r668\ProtoGen.
I followed the steps listed above, but i was still getting error, sub-type not found.

Just by hit and trial, I saw the generated code has global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible against all generated classes, I deleted this plus below 3 lines from all generated class
private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension extensionObject;
    global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
      { return global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing); }

After this the error didnt come. I dont know why it helped, but it worked.